# create a session as error displayer for forms or functions error

Tags: php, sql, database, session, alert

I am developing a site and I am quite new to the subject. I had an idea of making a session variable that contains forms and functions errors or successful alerts. Instead of redirecting to the same page. Also, overcoming the problem of displaying success alerts in case of redirect to some php engine page. Furthermore, the ability to store alert display after page header redirect for cleaning variables so refresh page wont make the same request and add sql line to database.

alerts such as : *user added to database successfully*.

I hope my introduction is clear. i would like to know what developers here think about this idea. as terms of good practice or bad . is there any other way that you use. im sure im not the first one to think about it.

i would appreciate any help given on the subject

```
if (isset ($_POST['name']))
  //doing something
else
  $_SESSION['errors'] .= bla bla fill all;
```

another example:

```
$success = mail($emailto, $subject, $message, "From: <$EmailFrom>");
if ($success)
     $_SESSION['errors'] .= email has been sent successfully;
```

and than echo the session variable at index or any other page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hello friend**

As you said you are new to the language ... i would say the thought process is very nice as being a beginner ... but their are some issues while using session for the the errors and messages ...

1) session values can be easily modifiable like $_SESSION['err'] = "i have changed the val";
2) session to use generally is an expensive process to use . they needed to be start then destroyed too else they consume server space 
3) if session destroyed by the users via browsers no err, no msg will be displayed , only fatal err will occurs

solution : **use constants**

like:

```
define("value", "please enter the value");
define("name", "please enter the name");
define("age", "please enter the age");
```

use can place all constant in one file in any directory and just include the file where u want to use the error / constant variable like

```
include('err.php');
```

i hope this may be helpful for you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use cookies for that.

```
if (isset ($_POST['name']))
  //doing something
else
  setcookie("msg","Successfully inserted",time()+5,"/");
  header("location:index.php");
  exit;
```

and in `index.php:`

```
<?php if(isset($_COOKIE['msg'])){?>
    <span><?php echo $_COOKIE['msg'];setcookie("msg","",time()-5,"/");?></span> 
<?php }?>
```